# How to configure firewall with multiple provider on Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony4, firewall, provider

I'm writing this message to ask you how to launch my Symfony app with multiple user providers? This is my security yaml:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto


    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, app_user_provider]
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    foo: { password: test , roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
#            memory:
#                users:
#                    admin: { password: '123412A' ,roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']}
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
#            form_login:
#                csrf_token_generator : security.csrf.token_manager
            anonymous: true

            logout:
                path: app_logout
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UtilisateurAuthenticator

                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/Conversation , roles: [ROLE_ADMIN , ROLE_USER] }
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I get this error message, how to solve it?

> *Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "guard" listener on "main" firewall
> is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider.*

Answer (score 2):

You just need to declare the user provider you want to use within your `main` firewall. It must be one of those declared under the `providers` key.

```yaml
# security.yaml
# ...

main:
    provider: chain_provider # or app_user_provider or in_memory
    form_login: 
    # ...
```

Comment: from where do you take this info ?

Comment: Indeed i can't find a document page mentioning it, I guess it used to exist... Anyway, you can always use the `bin/console debug:config security` or `bin/console config:dump security` to see either current or available configuration keys. If the answer solves your issue, don't forget to accept it.